# How to force JAXB Unmarshal using setters?

Tags: jaxb

While unmarshalling, I need to validate whether value is within certain range. I am planning to add this validation in setter. How can I force JAXB to use setter while unmarshalling? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following:

1. Make sure you are mapping the property (get/set methods) and not the field (instance variable)

   1. Ensure you are not using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class.
   2. For annotations you do provide put them on the get (or set) method and not the field.
2. You have a properly matched get/set pair

   ```
   public String getFoo() {
       return this.foo;
   } 

   public void setFoo(String foo) {
       this.foo = foo;
   }
   ```
3. For a collection property the set will only be called if it has a value of `null` when the `get` is first called after the object is instantiated (i.e. you are not initializing it to an empty collection).