# JAXB: Separating the implementation of an element from the marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML structure which looks like this:

```
<root>
  <user></user>
  <data></data>
  <things-map>
    <item>
      <key>one</key>
      <value>Eins</key>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>two</key>
      <value>Zwei</key>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>three</key>
      <value>Drei</key>
    </item>
  </things-map>
</root>
```

I would like to unmarshall this into the following structure:

```
public class Root {
  // These are unimportant.
  private String user;
  private String data;

  private ThingsMap thingsMap;
}
```

Where the `ThingsMap` class is essentially a wrapper for the map given by `things-map`.

```
public class ThingsMap {
  private Map<String, String> items;

  @XmlElement(name = "item")
  public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = new Hashmap();
    for (List item : items) {
      this.items.put(items.key(), items.value());
    }
  }

  public List<Item> getItems() {
  List items = new ArrayList();
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : this.items.entrySet()) {
    items.add(new Item(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
  }
  return items;
}
```

The `Item` class can be inferred from there. It's a basic `Element`.

It is a similar issue to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930396/is-it-possible-to-ignore-a-wrapper-class-during-jaxb-marshalling).

The issue with this is, JAXB prefers to call the getter to get the list of items and then deal with it directly *(is this not ridiculous...?)*. *Unless* [the list returned is `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610149/how-to-force-jaxb-unmarshal-using-setters). I.e.

```
if (this.items == null) {
  return null;
}
```

However, trying this, the items passed to `setItems` is empty.

I do not want a regular Map, which I'm aware could be done with an Adapter. And as far as I can see, using an Adapter for this case requires a wrapper (which I do not want).